# Consistent naming of JavaScript method tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Some JavaScript tags are named in the [window.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window.*) fashion, while others are named as [javascript-*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript*) tags. Which of these is more standard, and should these tags be renamed?

Comment: They look good to me as how they are because in javascript there are methods like `window.open`, `window.load`.. and the events related to javascript are `javascript-events`.. if this is not what you mean, can you explain it clearly?

Comment: @Mr_Green: for example, [tag:javascript-alert]

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That one's unfortunate. :( It doesn't have another object it belongs to, like all of the window and document functions.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Oh right, global object. :) That one may make a case for being renamed then...

Answer (score 3):

Both are standard and correct. Neither set should be renamed. They simply follow two different standards, because they describe two different kinds of things.

- [window.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window.*) tags (and [document.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document.*) tags): all of these are actual functions or objects within the JavaScript language or libraries. They're analogous to the many tags discussing specific objects or classes in other languages, or the [system.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.*) tags covering various namespaces.
- [javascript-*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-*) tags: all of these are JavaScript *concepts*, not exact things that exist within the language.